# Angularfire2 5.0 Firebase data display query on ionic template

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

Hello guys I'm having problem using angularfire2 v 5.0. I used for a while 
 the v 4.0, now I'm trying to program with the v 5.0 and facing some issues.

How can I display a Firebase realtimedata in a label/input on ionic 3.0? I used to subscribe without problem with v 4.0 now I don't understand. When I use my code I can display on the console.log, but not on the template.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-keyboard',
  templateUrl: 'keyboard.html',
})

export class KeyboardPage {


 userNachna: Text;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public databaseFirebase: AngularFireDatabase,   
  ) {

  }

loadDataFirebase(){
this.databaseFirebase.object('/test/').snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe(action => {
    console.log(action.type);                <-- WORKS
    console.log(action.key)                  <-- WORKS
    console.log(action.payload.val())        <-- WORKS
    this.userNachna = action.payload.val();  <-- HERE THE ERROR
  });
}
```

My template IONIC 3.0 :

```
<ion-input type="text" #userNachna></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

the template probably should probably look alike:

```
<ion-input type="text" value="{{action.payload.value}}></ion-input>
```